# how to find the name of employee from 1st table with 2nd highest and 3rd lowest salary from salary column in 2nd table without sort in ABAP

Tags: abap

So , i have created following 2 internal tables and i want to find the name of employee from first table with 2nd highest and 3rd lowest base_salary which are present in 2nd table.

```
TYPES : BEGIN OF s_empdetails,

          empid       TYPE zsp_empid,
          fname       TYPE zsp_fname,
          lname       TYPE zsp_lname,
          location    TYPE zsp_loc,
          designation TYPE zsp_desig,
          bdate       TYPE zsp_bdate,
        END OF s_empdetails.

TYPES : BEGIN OF s_empsal,

          empid    TYPE zsp_empid,
          base_sal TYPE zsp_basesal,
          hra      TYPE zsp_hra,
          pf       TYPE zsp_pf,
          pt       TYPE zsp_pt,
          sp_all   TYPE zsp_splall,
        END OF s_empsal.

DATA : gt_emp_details  TYPE TABLE OF s_empdetails,
       gwa_emp_details TYPE s_empdetails.

DATA : gt_emp_sal  TYPE TABLE OF s_empsal,
       gwa_emp_sal TYPE s_empsal.


        SORT gt_items BY base_sal DESCENDING.
    
    READ TABLE gt_items INTO gwa_items INDEX 2 .
    
    WRITE 'Employee with 2nd highest Salary - '.
    
    READ TABLE gt_header INTO gwa_header WITH KEY empid = gwa_items-empid.
    
    WRITE gwa_header-fname.
```

but i want to find the employee name without using sort.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried directly with sort by descending and ascending and then getting the id's using index . but i want method without sort.

Comment: you didn't show anything from your trials except data declaration

Comment: sorry about that , i have edited it now .

Comment: And I guess adding a secondary sorted key to those tables would be cheating?

Comment: what is the reason for avoiding sorting?

Comment: actually , i just came along such question while practicing .

Answer (score 0):

Your internal table contents must come from the database query. So the solution is to adopt this query, so it retrieves the minimal subset of relevant entries.

You will get second highest with:

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM emp_salary
ORDER BY base_salary DESCENDING
INTO TABLE @DATA(result)
UP TO 2 ROWS.

read table result index 2.
```

and the third lowest with:

```
SELECT emp_id
FROM emp_salary
ORDER BY base_salary ASCENDING
INTO TABLE @DATA(result)
UP TO 3 ROWS.

read table result index 3.
```

Comment: actually i appended the 10 entries into the internal table manually and trying to find max ,min salary from it. how can i get it? select query doesnt work on internal tables ,right?

Comment: Select does work on internal tables: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect_itab.htm